# Spring Security 5 / Login / REST API Accessibility / Bad Credentials even if they are right?

Tags: java, rest, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

I am implementing a REST API using Spring Boot (2.0.1) to work with MongoDB (3.6). I'm really stuck. I've also tried other tips from StackOverFlow but it didn't help for some reason.

I have configured the SecurityConfig.java to permit the access to certain areas and also created a User inMemoryAuthentication, to be able to login to HAL Browser (Spring) and etc. But the problem is, that whatever address I put in browser I get a Login form and the credentials used in the inMemoryAuthentication is always wrong for some reason. The only way I've found to access the API is by excluding SecurityAutoConfiguration in the main class. But this opens up every permission to access everything including HAL Browser without authentication.

Would someone show me what I am doing wrong? I want to permit only certain paths/addresses to everyone, permit everything else only to use with TokenAuthentication (have already a custom implementation of it) and have one user (username, password) to access HAL Browser.

Here is my SecurityConfig.java:

```
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    @Autowired
    protected SecurityConfig(final TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService) {
        super();
        this.tokenAuthenticationService = tokenAuthenticationService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .addFilterBefore(new TokenAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/hello").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/test2").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/useraccount").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
//      auth
//              .inMemoryAuthentication()
//              .withUser("user1").password("password").roles("ADMIN");
        auth
                .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder().username("user").password("password").roles("USER"));
//      auth
//              .userDetailsService(userService);
    }

//    @Bean
//    @Override
//    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
//        UserDetails user =
//                User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
//                        .username("user")
//                        .password("password")
//                        .roles("USER")
//                        .build();
//
//        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
//    }

//    @Bean
//    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
//        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
//        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user").password("pass").roles("USER", "ADMIN").build());
//        return manager;
//    }

}
```

I've tried different approaches as you see (commented blocks) but still no luck.
Even though I have `permitAll()` on `/register`, i still get the auto generated login form, which won't accept any credentials.

So as i've said earlier the only way to use my API is to exclude the SecurityAutoConfiguration (`@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class`) but it is not a secure option.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see, it's likely that your `SecurityConfig` class never gets called, as it doesn't have any annotation indicating to Spring Boot that it should  look for beans to autowire in the class (`@Autowired`)

To give you an idea, the following will never be called:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("This will never called");
    }

}
```

Whereas, if we had `@EnableWebSecurity`:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("This is called");
    }

}
```

Keep in mind that Spring Boot will not detect annotations inside a class if the class itself is not annotated with `@Component` or with another annotation that inherits the `@Component` annotation (such as `@Configuration`, `@Service`, ...)

---

**EDIT**: I quickly put together a program to imitate your situation:

`SecurityConfiguration.java`:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser(new User("root", "root", Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"))))
                .passwordEncoder(fakePasswordEncoder());
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder fakePasswordEncoder() {
        return new PasswordEncoder() {
            @Override
            public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
                return null; // matches(...) will always return true anyways
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
                return true;
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/hello").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/test2").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/useraccount").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin().permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).permitAll();
    }

}
```

*Note that I just quickly made a password encoder that ignores the password because that would require more work*

`ExampleController.java`:

```
@RestController
public class ExampleController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public Object index() {
        return getCurrentUser();
    }


    public Object getCurrentUser() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return ((UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken)auth).getPrincipal();
    }

}
```

And when I login with the username `root` and the any password (*remember, the fake password encoder doesn't care about the password*), it redirects me to `/` and displays the following:

`{"password":null,"username":"root","authorities":[{"authority":"USER"}],"accountNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"enabled":true}`

*(which is normal because that's what I'm making it output)*

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! I had some compiling problems with my project first, so i've rewritten it again into an empty project and apparently forgotten the @EnableWebSecurity. My mistake.
I will try you password method as well. Thanks for the tipp!

Comment: I would like to ask you one more thing. Now whenever i login, spring redirects me back to the login page, even if i've logged in successfully. Is there a way to make spring redirect to a HAL Browser, which is located at "/" or just straight to some other address i request in browser or remember the logged in user and let me surf the server without asking to login every time?